# How to dynamically populate a choices widget in symfony?

Tags: forms, symfony1, field

Suppose there is an `image_url` column in database.

I want the user to choose from several recommended images,which is something like this:

```
<input type="radio" value="domain.com/path_to_img1" name="image_url" />
<img src="domain.com/path_to_img1" />
<input type="radio" value="domain.com/path_to_img2" name="image_url" />
<img src="domain.com/path_to_img2" />
```

Where the image urls are generated on the fly.

How to do this in a symfony flavor by `sfForm`?

I tried this:

```
$form->widgetSchema['key'] = new sfWidgetFormSelect(...)
```

But get a fatal error:

> Cannot access protected property

But what's the exact way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, standart approach is to write a widget.

In your concrete case it seems you actually want to perform a choice, right? So you have to implement another `sfWidgetFormChoice` renderer. To do that, inherit `sfWidgetFormSelectRadio` (let's call them `sfWidgetFormSelectRadioImage`) to learn them to render labels as `<img>` tags. Then ask `sfWidgetFormChoice` explicitly to render itself with `sfWidgetFormSelectRadioImage` class, and that should be all.

Comment: Can you illustrate with an example?

Comment: No, right now I can't. Hint: dig into and override `sfWidgetFormSelectRadio::render()`.

Comment: Thanks.But I can't find the code to **dynamically** populate the options there.

Comment: @user198729 what you mean by "dynamically"? Can you describe how it should look like?

I think you just have to pass urls as options' labels.

Answer (score 0):

In your form configuration insert the following:

```
$this->widgetSchema['choices'] = new sfWidgetFormChoice (array('choices' => $custom_values_array));
```

Comment: Can't you move the logic behind the building of $custom_values_array from the action to the form?